# Does the fact a table is big can impact the overall performance of a PostgreSQL server?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

If I have a table that is getting bigger and bigger (i.e. it is taking more and more storage space - currently 65GB), can this affect the overall performance of the PostgreSQL server, e.g. impact the speed of queries on other tables?

This is for a PostgreSQL 9.6 database (we plan to upgrade to 10 -> 11 -> 12 later this year), hosted on Google Cloud (Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL).

Comment: At least with "vanilla" Postgres you can go directly from 9.6 to 12, no need for three different migrations.

Comment: Something you should consider as you migrate to the modern releases of postgres is table partitioning- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-partitioning.html . PG can handle very large tables just fine, but there are advantages to partitioning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this shouldn't affect the speed of queries for other tables.

One way it could *indirectly* affect the speed is, if you regularly run queries against that big table and retrieve many rows from there (either directly or indirectly e.g. because of a Seq Scan). This could then cause data from other (smaller) tables to be evicted from the cache.

Then a query using one of the other tables needs to retrieve the data again from the hard disk which of course is slower than from cache.